# How can I freeze the first row of the second sheet in an excel-export?

Tags: jasper-reports, export-to-excel

I'm trying to freeze the first row on the second sheet of my excle export from a jasper report, but it freezes another row. In my example code below it freezes the first two rows on the second sheet, but if there are more rows on the first sheet the number of rows frozen on the second sheet are even higher. It seems like it "adds" the number of rows from the first sheet on top of the second sheet, so if there are e.g. 9 rows on the first sheet and I try to freeze the first row on the second sheet, it freezes the 10th row on my second sheet.
Is this a bug in jasper-reports or am I doing something wrong here? Does Anybody know how to solve this problem in another way?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="RowBreakTest" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="0292da25-2332-41a0-8f81-fcbe04339e99">
    <title>
        <band height="28">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="280" height="14" />
                <text><![CDATA[This is just the first sheet]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="14" width="280" height="14" />
                <text><![CDATA[]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="280" y="0" width="270" height="14" />
                <text><![CDATA[]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="280" y="14" width="270" height="14" />
                <text><![CDATA[]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </title>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="14" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="280" height="14">
                    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.break.before.row" value="true"/>
                    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.freeze.column.edge" value="Left"/>
                </reportElement>
                <text><![CDATA[header on 2nd sheet]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="280" y="0" width="270" height="14">
                    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.freeze.row.edge" value="Bottom"/>
                </reportElement>
                <text><![CDATA[more header on 2nd sheet]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="28" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="280" height="14" />
                <text><![CDATA[data]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="14" width="280" height="14" />
                <text><![CDATA[more data]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="280" y="0" width="270" height="14" />
                <text><![CDATA[even more data]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="280" y="14" width="270" height="14"/>
                <text><![CDATA[a lot more data]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: Do you have only 1 columns as in example? because I think what you are seeing is that you are not defining the edges (in your example there is only 1 edge), Normally if in column header, you would freeze first field "Left" and last "Bottom"

Comment: No, the original report has multiple columns. I tried your suggestion, adding the `net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.freeze.column.edge` property. It just freezes the the first column, as I would expect it, but it doesn't change the row freeze behavior, I still have the sheet frozen at the 10th row and the first column, but I just want to freeze the 1 row.

Comment: add "Left" to first column/filed in header then "Bottom" to last column/field in header. That should freeze all the fields in between

Comment: Sorry, but that's exactly what I tried, it just freezes the first column in addition, but it doesn't change the frozen row.

Comment: That is the way to do it and it should work, if I remember correctly Jasper reports also have an example on git that you can check.

Comment: Yes, thats what I thought too. It should work, but it doesn't. As long as I don't use the 'net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.break.before.row' property it works as you said and as I would exoect it, but if I want multiple sheets and I use that property it doesn't work that way anymore. I've changed my example to multiple columns and added the properties as you suggested, but it still doesn't freeze the header row.

Comment: yes I can confirm, it seems very buggy, currently I have no other idea then trying to avoid that break property and use normal page break.. but yeah buggy stuff is always buggy.